# How to use DESCRIBE INPUT in CSDK 3.7?

Tags: informix

DESCRIBE INPUT is returning -1834 when used with a dynamic query in CSDK 3.70.  For example:

```
select field1, field2 from table where field3 = 'A'
```

With the CSDK 3.50, this worked without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it worked in CSDK 3.50, it should still work in CSDK 3.70.

I seem to remember a bug fixed recently related to getting an error when there are no input parameters to describe, as in the example.  You should just get a descriptor with zero descriptions.

So, contact IBM (Informix) Technical Support.